# Where do I see the iOS Distribution Provision Profile expiration date with iOS 8?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have several apps that are using enterprise distribution provision profiles for apps on iOS 8. With previous versions of iOS, I could find the expiration dates of these profiles on my device by going to General -> Profiles... this is no longer the case with iOS 8. How can I see the expiration dates on the profiles on the device? I see the dates on the dev portal but I would like to be able to see this information on the device too since not all the profiles apply for each app/device.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 8, you can no longer see the profile expiration dates on the device. Unfortunately, Apple is assuming you'll manage the upcoming expirations through some other process.  I know this isn't what you want to hear, but Apple has made a concious decision to remove the information from the device Settings app.

In this years device management WWDC talk (at about 42 minutes in), the speaker confirmed this with the following: "Provisioning profiles no longer appear at all in Settings because its handled completely automatically. The device will automatically prune expired provisioning profiles when they are no longer needed."

Comment: I don't like their approach but I appreciate your reply! I wish we could just renew the profile from the dev portal without redistributing!

Answer (score 3):

You may not be able to see the profile's expiration date on the device's settings. 
However, you could read the expiration date and other information from your application. The provisioning profile is embedded in your application's bundle and you could read it like this

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"embedded.mobileprovision" ofType:nil]
```

Then you can parse the file and get all the info you need.

You can see the structure of the file if you type the following command in a terminal window

```
security cms -D -i /.../.../myapp.app/embedded.mobileprovision
```

You will have to replace the dots and myapp.app with your actual data